# jquery bootstrap selector inside popover

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, bootstrap-popover

I have a bootstrap popover like this :

```
<span style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="manual" data-html="true" data-placement="top" class="label label-primary bootpopover" data-content='<div class="input-group"><input type="text" style="cursor:text;background:none;" class="form-control input-sm" onmousemove="this.select()" value="http://example.com" readonly><span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm link" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" type="button">Go<i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i>Go</button></span></div>' title="" data-original-title="<i>Title</i>">Link1</span>
```

but everytime I try to select link class on jquery it doesn't work.

```
$( ".link" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert("redirecting");
});
```

Comment: please someone help!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a `.link` in the HTML at that point - all you have is a `span` whose `data-content` happens to contain an HTML string that contains a `.link` *when put into the document*. Either attach the listener when the popover appears, or use event delegation instead:

```
$(document).on("click", ".link", function() {
  alert("redirecting");
});
```